# Doors and guards

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/n-doors-k-monkeys) but noticeably different

You are the leader of the guard in the dungeon of an ancient castle.
There are `N` doors  in the dungeon and `N` guards with keys.
Guard with index `i` may operates with doors
that have multiple indexes:
`i, 2 * i, 3 * i, ...`

The way he operates is very dumb: he just toggles state of the door:
"open" → "close", "close" → "open".
Every morning you are given two lists:

- the list of doors that are open now (criminally or legally)
- the list of doors that must be open after your shift

*Your goal is to select the minimum number of guards to accomplish the task.*

Each guard from your selected team passes through all his doors (scan and opens/closes them),
but only once and only one way, starting from the first guard in the list.

#### Examples

Number of doors: `1001`
Doors are opened: `[ ]`
Doors must be opened: `[ ]`
Answer: `[ ]`

Number of doors: `10`
Doors are opened: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
Doors must be opened: `[ ]`
Answer: `[1]`  (First guard closes all doors)

Number of doors: `5`
Doors are opened: `[1, 2, 3]`
Doors must be opened: `[3, 4, 5]`
Answer: `[1, 3]`  (After guard #1 doors `[4, 5]` are opened, and guard #3 just open door #3)

#### Input

- Number of doors N
- List of doors are opened now
- List of doors must be opened

Every list is valid: no negative or `> N` numbers, duplicates etc.
Also you may suppose that lists are sorted as you need:
by ascending or descending.

#### Output

Any of teams of guards (that resolves the task) with minimal number of members.

#### About solution

I remember that there should be considerations from the number theory that either solve the problem in a closed form or greatly optimize searching. But I can’t formulate them yet.

#### Test cases

```
6, [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5] → [2, 4, 5, 6]  
8, [1, 8], [4] → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
100, [12], [13] → [12, 13, 24, 26, 36, 39, 60, 65, 72, 78, 84, 91 ]
```

Comment: I suspect that guard \$k\$ should be included if and only if you need to toggle an odd number of doors of the form \$k/d\$ with \$d\$ square-free.

Comment: @Nitrodon It's interesting, but what about even number of doors?
Could it help to get closed form solution?

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

Expects `(source, target)(N)`, where the first two arguments are sets. Returns an array.

```javascript
(a,b,o=q=[])=>g=n=>++q>n?o:g(n,o.map(v=>p^=q%v<1,p=a.has(q)^b.has(q))|p&&o.push(q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7BbsIwDAbg@57Cl1WJ8ErTMlrQXB6CIwpSYKXdxJKUsu6ydy8OIASHLZKl5Lf1OZ@mN9328OGPL9a9V8OOBmFwg45aWmlJZU2WytGoLe3CzWth0cVfxoueSr@m9rl/U@jJxI3pRCvXm@tF/voocrH/7prwGrbOdm5fxXtXi52w1Q8sq6NYpQgZwkRLhFsWAoRXLaWYSgnjMYSxECFMNcDTH5ZCKB6gSSAKJm4nWDx23XoREfL/0PSBVFkwVZLcqWeUScVmymjKZBZqxnrCxVty7ucFf5D7M6WHEw)

#### Commented

```javascript
(                  // outer function taking:
  a,               //   a   = set of currently open doors
  b,               //   b   = target set of opened doors
  o =              //   o[] = output list
  q = []           //   q   = counter, initially zero'ish
) =>               //
g = n =>           // inner recursive function taking n
++q > n ?          // increment q; if it's greater than n:
  o                //   stop and return o[]
:                  // else:
  g(               //   do a recursive call:
    n,             //     pass n unchanged
    o.map(v =>     //     for each entry v in o[]:
      p ^=         //       toggle p if:
        q % v < 1, //         v is a divisor of q
      p =          //       start with p set to:
        a.has(q) ^ //         the presence of q in a
        b.has(q)   //         XOR the presence of q in b
    ) |            //     end of map()
    p &&           //     if p is truthy:
      o.push(q)    //       append q to o[]
  )                //   end of recursive call
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
≔⁺⁻ηζ⁻ζηηＷ⌊η«≔Φ…·¹θ⁻¬﹪κι№ηκη⟦Ｉι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY29CsIwFEZn@xR3TCBCq6OTFASHSnEtGUINzaVpgk1SoeKzxwR/lgP3cDlfr8TcW6FjPDqHgyGtDo40aBIVg5Uy@BwrA0VpxqF4KNQS8hdOYSLJw7PYfAMn1F7O5Gz6VMJFXoUZJKkY3P@ti/WksbegLRkZYM7WNhifF0f6W9m0MybX1cJ5gpQn9Yqxq8qSQVfteOae87hd9Bs) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁺⁻ηζ⁻ζηη
```

Get the list of doors that need to be toggled.

```
Ｗ⌊η«
```

While there are doors remaining, get the next guard needed.

```
≔Φ…·¹θ⁻¬﹪κι№ηκη
```

Calculate the new list of doors that need to be toggled.

```
⟦Ｉι
```

Output the guard.

Comment: Cool! `1000` doors just for 1.7 s!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
«Ð¢Ï[W,©g!#Lʒ®ßÖ®yå^
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259704/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

Inputs in the order \$[openDoors], [doorsToBeOpened], numberOfDoors\$; outputs the results on separated lines to STDOUT.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9vc2FiaWX//8Krw5DCosOPW1cswqlnISNMypLCrsOfw5bCrnnDpV7//1sxMl0KWzEzXQoxMDD/LS1uby1sYXp5) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@pw6XkX1oC5epUJoT@P7T68IRDiw73R4frHFqZrqgc4XNq0qF1h@cfnnZoXeXhpXH/a2sPbbP/Hx0dHasDRIYGBoaxOgrR0YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWQCmoCoQ8UACsJhaEgIJgLQhBM6hKC6AQUNgCwjUC8gyNwVbFxv7X1c3L181JrKoEAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
«      # Merge the first two (implicit) input-lists together
 Ð     # Triplicate this list
  ¢    # Pop two copies, and get the counts of each item
   Ï   # Only leave the items where the count is 1
       # (we now have an unordered list of unique items of the merged input-lists)
[      # Start an infinite loop:
 W     #  Push the minimum of the list (without popping the list itself)
  ,    #  Pop and print this minimum with trailing newline
 ©     #  Store the list in variable `®` (without popping)
  g    #  Pop and push the length of the list
   !   #  Faculty (edge case for an empty input-lists)
    #  #  If this length! equals 1 (aka length is 0 or 1): stop the infinite loop
 L     #  Push a list in the range [1, third (implicit) input-integer]
  ʒ    #  Filter it by:
   ®ß  #   Push the minimum of list `®` again
     Ö #   Check if the current item is divisible by this minimum
   ®   #   Push list `®` again
    yå #   Check if the current item is in list `®`
   ^   #   Bitwise-XOR to check either of the two is truthy (but not both!)
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 311 bytes

```py
R=range
V=lambda i,o:{j for j in o if 0==j%i}
def f(n,o,O):
 q=[(o:={*o},{*R(1,n+1)}-o,[])]
 for o,c,p in q:
  if[*o]==O:return p
  for i in R(min({*o,*O}),n+1):
   if i>max(p+[0])and(C:=V(i,{*o,*O})):
    U=V(i,c);Q={*(o-C),*U}
    if not(t:={j for j in Q if j not in O})or i<=min(t):q+=[(Q,{*(c-U),*C},p+[i])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9PT4NAEMXvfIq5mMzSacL2jyK6XvoBmjZpL4QDtqBL7C4lmGgaPjvOYNVqvMG89377Xv3ePns3jeum79emyd1TEWzNS3543OdgySenCkrfQAXWgQdbQmRMdWW7YF@UUKIjT0uVBHA0KfrEnELf0SlcoyY30qobe0ozlQUDxNOOagEdOcCsNPSZMcukKdrXxkHNR7FZsazxYB0yjsJlpwaYhKSBfTjkb1iP0ihTudvjIjFbtPTl/fTBZjju1N2KS6EfLxSFm26QmOF8iy3XvVi3knslivwxSKrcG6nRquQ44oErfgR34w2jFh1xA8vb@rqxrsUSdRRpXiuDVfBzpFQTTAimBDOCOcE1wQ1BTHBLoKM//vm3nYVz5FLncHqGZfz5j4PBgohFnv2uEok0EUFPWek/AA)